# Uncaught ReferenceError: sample is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, error-handling, reference

Please JS and inspect experts help me solve this out,

I see this error when I create any page that has google maps with my WordPress theme I see it on inspect element right now.

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: compileposh is not defined
  at crossBrowserFixes (publicjava.js:9471)
  at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (publicjava.js:9532)
  at i (jquery.js:2)
  at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:2)
  at Function.ready (jquery.js:2)
  at HTMLDocument.K (jquery.js:2)
```

What do all the above mean? I have a compileposh reference but why it's not defined ?

the **error** lines codes added at below:

```
 9470   //remove ajaxy from single posts when using Disqus
 9471   if(compileposh.disqusComments == 'true') 
 $(
     '#post-zone article a, 
     .blog_next_prev_buttons a, 
     #portfolio-nav #prev-link a, 
     #portfolio-nav #next-link a, 
     .portfolio-items 
     .col 
     .work-item 
     .work-info a'
 ).addClass('no-ajaxy');
```

this code located at `publicjava.js` file located on `themefile/js/publicjava.js` and called from `functions.php` also I have a `map.js` file but the map section I used is a plugin - and I have original theme options that I declared on public java but with all tryings the same error coming to inspect element.

also, there are some more error lines: `publicjava.js 9532`

```
 9532    crossBrowserFixes();
```

and `jquery.js` that not included with my theme : `jquery.js: 2`

and this at bottom :

```
chrome-extension://foobgjfmnkeainefnnoeghobcdcidhme/javascripts/content_script.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search For:

**`wp_localize_script`**

in your **`WordPress`** theme files. May be in **`functions.php`** or search for the whole project.

you can also search for **`compilelove`**. and change it to **`compileposh`**.